# How are you supposed to center a profile picture on mobile?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application

What is the proper way to do it?

Are you supposed to just center the text and put the profile picture to one side? Or do you center the entire thing together?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to understand how to align objects within a container frame is to abstract from the real object (the mobile), sketch with high visual contrast, and check the resulting white spaces.

- The container frame is an orthogonal shape.
- The alignment must be at the top edge
- The element to align is made up of two figures: photo and text

The spaces that offer the best visual proportion are those resulting from aligning the grouped element:

[image]